# What is the difference between for each ( in ) and for ( : )?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

As someone who has a background in python, I was quite surprised when I first saw the `for ( : )` loop:

```
vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4};
int sum = 0;
for (int i : vec){
    sum += i;
}
//sum is now 10
```

This is a very useful construct and should probably be used whenever you don't need the index of a value multiple times.

But today I found there also is a `for each ( in )` loop, used like this:

```
vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4};
int sum = 0;
for each (int i in vec){
    sum += i;
}
//sum is now 10
```

Interestingly, google results for the second one are mostly related to Microsoft, not the usual c++ reference websites.

*What are the differences between these two loops?*

Comment: The first one is standard c++ (c++11 to be precise), the second one is probably done with macros or is compiler specific and not standard.

Comment: 2nd one is C++/CLI or C++/CX syntax for iterating through an object that implements IEnumerable interface. First one is regular syntax for C++ 11 iterators.

Comment: @Stefan We can rule out the macro-option, they are highlighted in purple in VS2013. It looks like a regular keyword. But yes, it seems to be non-c++11.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first is called a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and is a C++11 feature of the language. It allows you to iterate like that over ranges that have a begin() and end() method available (member or non-member) or are arrays.

The second is a Microsoft specific syntax, available for C++/CLI but also made available to C++. It allows to iterate through an array or collection. Its use is not recommended and the range-based for loop should be preferred. See [for each, in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202.aspx).

Comment: Microsoft loves to introduce stuff into C++ and then not recommend its use, it seems ;)
Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: This has been available in VC++ since VS2005, 6 years before the completion of C++11 that introduced the range-based for loops.

Answer (score 4):

The for each loop is provided by Microsoft Visual C++.
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xey702bw%28VS.80%29.aspx

It is not standard C++ and is quite old (introduced in VS2005). The compiler (VS) converts this loop to proper for loops on compile.

So it is best to stick with regular `for ( ; ; )` loops or the `for ( : )` loop to allow compatibility with other compiles such as g++.

Comment: So do I understand correctly they introduced `for each` before C++11 was finalized?

Comment: C++11 was 'finalized' in 2011 so yes, much earlier than that.